# Why does the law still require the usage of catalytic converters in cars?

Tags: environmental-policy

Many countries have decided that cars need catalytic converters despite the fact that they lower efficiency and produce more carbon dioxide for the same mechanical power output.

The gases the catalytic converters combust, like carbon monoxide, hydrocarbons and nitrogen oxides, are not dangerous in the concentrations they often appear, and they spontaneously react to become other chemicals after some time in the atmosphere.

Catalytic converters were introduced 35 years ago when environment policies and car configurability were different. I don't question the motives of why the laws were passed then. **Today there is a big focus on reducing carbon dioxide emissions, so why are catalytic converters still required by law?** Catalytic conversion can be avoided with just a software or configuration change in the engine control unit and that would reduce carbon dioxide emissions by some percent.

A solution could be an adaptive system that configures combustion depending on circumstances, like turning off the oxygen supply to the catalytic converter when the car is moving at higher speed and turning it on in confined spaces like parking places. It could also easily be turned off and on depending on geographic location like in smoggy cities.

**Why does the law require the usage of catalytic converters in cars?**

The setting of the engine control unit is the direct cause of increased fuel consumption, since the combustion process in the engine cylinder is providing more air than is optimal in order to provide oxygen to the combustion in the catalytic converter. [Back pressure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back_pressure) from the catalytic converter also decreases engine efficiency and increases fuel consumption. In some vehicles there is a [secondary air injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secondary_air_injection) to provide oxygen to the catalytic converter. This requires energy and increases fuel consumption.

For example in regard to carbon monoxide the catalytic converter can be deactivated when levels are within [WHO guidelines](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK138710/#ch2.s11) at 6 ppm. In common air CO levels are [0.1 ppm in the atmosphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbon_monoxide#Occurrence).

A common misunderstanding of this question is that people seems to think that I write that the total carbon dioxide produced per unit of fuel will be different with or without catalytic conversion. I have not written that. I write that there will be a difference per mechanical power produced.

Comment: This looks more like of a statement of opinion about a technical problem than a question about a political one.

Comment: I moved to Southern California in 1975, at the start of the switch to catalytic converters and when most cars on the road did not have them. My personal observations of nasty purple haze in the Los Angeles basin conflict with the second paragraph assertion of harmlessness.

Comment: @BrianZ The technical problem is not possible to discuss because people just refer to the legal requirement. I started this discussion with engine experts.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan It would be possible to automatically turn on the catalytic conversion based on location, although I am not sure that nasty purple haze is toxic.

Comment: "This question was first asked in Stack Exchange Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair where they bluntly wrote that catalytic converters were required by law." In that case, the ideal place to ask would probably be [Law.SE](https://law.stackexchange.com/). Sorry that you're being bandied around from stack to stack like this.

Comment: I don't think it is inappropriate to ask this question here; not every polity on Earth has chosen to mandate the use of catalytic converters in order to achieve the stated goals that requiring a catalytic converter are supposed to achieve. There is a legitimate environmental policy question here to wonder about that is very much on topic.

Comment: I also think the question makes sense since it is asking about why the law exists, which typically belongs to politics.

Comment: @DavidJonsson I think the issue with this question is that you're making the assumption that catalytic converters have no benefit. I think the massive reductions in smog since the '70s is good evidence that they do have real health and environmental benefits, though whether those benefits outweigh increased CO2 emissions is less clear. I think this would be a good question if you removed that assumption and asked why governments prioritize reducing smog and NO pollution over CO2 emissions.

Comment: On the other hand, if you really doubt that they have any benefit at all, maybe ask about the technical aspects without the "why?" on Motor Vehicle SE. Something like "Do catalytic converters have health and environmental benefits?"

Comment: Out of curiosity when did you post this on MV&R SE? I ask because it's not associated on your account, there's no matching closed question and there's no matching deleted question in the past 30 days either. While the current form of the question may well be off-topic there as it currently stands you're suggesting you got a "blunt" reception when you asked at MV, yet I can find no evidence you asked it there at all.

Comment: @divibisan I stressed that the catalytic converter can be activaded and deactivated depending on external conditions. It could be kept in smoggy areas. I did ask in SE biology or chemistry about the danger of nitrogen oxides, alkanes and carbon monoxide without result. I asked more than a month ago so questions are deleted. Maybe someone else can ask who knows the formal requirements from start? Even if I improve a question after deletion it is most often not opened.

Comment: Someone sugested the issue to be managed in Law SE instead, so I rewrote the question to not assume that it is not always illegall, which the off-topic classification here imply. See https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/52732/does-the-law-require-permanent-usage-of-catalytic-converters-in-cars

Comment: I am a chemist; unfortunately, I don’t know a lot about vehicle or engine construction. However, I think you have a bit of a wrong idea of how catalytic converters work and, most notably, how insignificant any reduction of carbon dioxide exhaust would be at the expense of increased carbon monoxide and unburnt/partially burnt fuel – a negative that would far outweigh any potential benefit. Assuming pure hexane as your petrol, 1 l will burn completely to give exactly 1.98 kg carbon dioxide – this is a basic high-school level calculation.

Comment: In reality, (especially in the olden days) the fuel will not burn completely but part of it will leave the exhaust as carbon monoxide or unburnt fuel. Thus, instead of emitting 1.98 kg you might be emitting 1.8 kg of carbon dioxide with the remainder of the carbon being unburnt fuel/carbon monoxide. However, whatever happens to that unburnt fuel/carbon monoxide, it will ultimately end up as carbon dioxide *anyway* giving us the total figure of 1.98 kg again. There is no gain from having that transformation later rather than earlier.

Comment: The fact that 1 l of hexane (approximated: petrol) will ultimately give 1.98 kg of carbon dioxide when burned is as fundamental as gravity existing; no way of doing or not doing chemistry (other than not burning the hexane) will change that. By adding the cat, you however get a better air quality and you get it sooner. It’s a similar story for the NOx’s, except you *absolutely don’t want them* in your engine exhaust as they *are* harmful and will remain as harmful NO2 in the concentrations they occur in in exhaust. See the German diesel scandal.

Comment: An old law needs to be motivated. Those who maintain the law has to show that the disadvantages are worse than the advantages, after a change in circumstances. "Carbon monoxide and unburnt/partially burnt fuel" are usually not a problem. They are only toxic at higher levels.  I wil update the question with some info on this.

Comment: @jan I write for the same mechanical power output. Momre hexane will be used for the same mechanical power output with catalytic conversion in use,compared to when not in use.

Comment: Adding the cat to the motor exhaust causes a decrease in power output in the single-digit percent range. Meanwhile, depending on which numbers on the respective German Wikipedia articles are better comparable, the generations of VW Golf from the 70’s to 2020 increased their petrol efficiency by something between 30 and 50 %. (Golf I: either 6.4 or 9.0 l/100 km; Golf VIII: 4.5 l/100 km) The Golf I was without cat at the time it was introduced; it didn’t become mandatory until 1993.

Comment: @Jan Adding a cat to a motor exhaust results in lots of meowing, scratches, and a weird smell once the meowing stops.

Comment: You are wrong about who has to prove the disadvantages versus the advantages. It is the group that would want to change the law to no longer require the catalytic convertors that have to prove it is better not to have them as they are the ones making the claims.

Answer (score 8):

Catalytic converters are [intended](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalytic_converter) to reduce more-toxic pollutant emissions in favor of less-toxic pollutant emissions, by a chemical reaction converting the former into the latter before they leave the exhaust port.

So, their use is a trade-off. I'm no chemist or car expert, but I suppose it's possible they lower efficiency somewhat. (Although - is that a significant reduction in efficiency? I kind of doubt it.) And indeed, they produce *more* of the less-toxic pollutants, e.g. carbon dioxide - but that's the intention.

Now, this is a politics website, so I'll say that in many countries, over the past decades, environmental considerations have come to carry more significance than in the earlier industrial times; and the reduced performance is not very cumbersome or noticeable to car owners and passengers (if they think about it at all), nor does it eat away at car-maker profits. So we have motivation to enforce the use of catalytic converters, and little apparent motivation to push back against it.

Comment: This question is something noone works with. I asked in Stack Exchange Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair and they refuse to discuss it because the law requires catalytic converters. The question is stuck.

Comment: @DavidJonsson: Yes, that's unfortunate, because your question is somewhere between politics and car technology... I gave you the best answer I have.

Comment: "the reduced performance is not very cumbersome or noticeable " rightly so because drivers just compensate that by pressing the throttle. The consequence is just noticeable in higher fuel consumption.